# mod_rewrite .htaccess redirect part of a query string

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

I'm struggling with a redirect problem. I need to redirect the following URL with mod_rewrite thorough .htaccess

```
http://www.mysite.com/somescript.php?&lang=php&var=1&var=2
```

to the following

```
http://www.mysite.com/somescript.php?lang=php&var=1&var=2
```

So, basically I just need to remove the

```
&
```

before

```
lang=php
```

However, the order is important. Sometimes

```
&lang=php
```

appears after other variables in the querystring. in this scenario I need the

```
&
```

to remain part of

```
&lang=php
```

Is this possible?

*To summarise, if &lang=php appears at the beginning of the query string, remove the &. If &lang=php appears anywhere else in the query string, the & must remain.*

Hope this is clear!

I would change the script myself but unfortunately I am not the developer, and he doesn't seem too helpful at the moment; this is a quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would replace `?&` with `?`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^somescript\.php$ /somescript.php?%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hi elusive, thanks for your reply. I tried this, obviously replacing somescipt.php, but it results in a internal server error? Any ideas?

Comment: Did you enable rewriting (`RewriteEngine On`)?

Comment: Yes, I enabled the rewrite engine. If you try it you will see it results in an internal sever error.

Comment: @Matt: There was a typo in my `RewriteCond`. Please try the corrected version.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your re-written suggestion. This time it does not result in a internal server error but unfortunately it doesn't remove the & from the querystring. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Could it be that the initial "?" is not part of the query string. The query string perhaps starts at the first "&"

Comment: @Matt: That is possible. Try removing it from the `RewriteCond` line.

Comment: @Matt: I changed my post accordingly (for the record).

Answer (score 1):

why don't you match `"?&"` and replace it by `"?"` ?

Something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?&(.*) $1?$2 [L]
```

(not tested)

Because I think the combination `"?&"` is never valid...(?)

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for your reply. I tried this, but nothing happened. It did not remove the &. I even tried it on a clean .htaccess file, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: oh, maybe you need to escape the ? like: RewriteRule ^(.*)\?&(.*) $1?$2 [L]

Comment: Thanks but this didn't work either. No change to the querystring. Any other suggestions? I'm afraid that I only have a very basic knowledge of .htaccess.

Comment: the regex seems to work, tested it here: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html Maybe you have a different problem...

Comment: Here is the following exact code used in a clean .htaccess file: 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?&(.*) $1?$2 [L]

When uploaded, the URL remains with the & inserted.

Confused.

Comment: This didn't work as the actual query string began at "&", not "?". Thanks for your help anyway.